# Does step load work in last locust versions (2.4.3)?

Tags: performance, locust

Is it possible to do step load on Locust version 2.4?
Link from this page https://docs.locust.io/en/1.2.3/running-locust-in-step-load-mode.html redirect to 404 page.

Comment: Have you tried the internet archive?  If the page has gone, that might find it.  Or, if it has moved, a broader Google search might turn it up.

Answer (score 1):

The page is just renamed. Here's the latest version https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/custom-load-shape.html